# Custom component

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am creating a Swing GUI, I am using a series of `JTextField`. I want to be able to add a custom property to the text field. This is going to be used to complete a calculation when focus is lost, for instance.

```
JTextField1.getCustomePram() * user input
```

I want a text field that will have a predefined value, it is for multiplying £20 * 5. So the default param will be 20 and the user will put the qty in, and on loss of focus the calculation will be done.

I am using Netbeans to build the GUI, I have tried extending the `JTextField` but to be honest I am not sure what to do, any advice or if I am going about this completely wrong please let me know.

Comment: depends of type of Property and reason why add any Property

Comment: I want a text field that will have a predefined value, it is for multiplying £20 * 5. So the default param will be 20 and the user will put the qty in, and on loss of focus the calculation will be done. WChargin answered the focus question, just need a bit of help with the custom param now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want a text field that will have a predefined value, it is for multiplying £20 * 5. So the default param will be 20 and the user will put the qty in, and on loss of focus the calculation will be done. .. if I am going about this completely wrong please let me know.

You're doing this completely wrong.

For this I might use either a disabled text field or label for the unit price (£20), and a [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) for the quantity (5).  Instead of doing the calculation on focus lost, [add a change listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#addChangeListener%28javax.swing.event.ChangeListener%29) and show the user the new sub-total (and total if relevant) of the ordered item(s) in 'real time' - when the quantity is changed.

> Need to look at how I need to implement ideas in Java.

A good place to look is the [Visual Guide to Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html).  Combine them in a layout for complex groups of components.

Comment: Which I could give more then +1. Instead of helping working himself in much trouble to extend a JTextField and do weird stuff with it, come with a decent solution with decent UI. Me likes.

Comment: Okay Thanks for your help I am going to have a rethink of how I am going to do this, I am new to Java and come from a PHP background. Need to look at how I need to implement ideas in Java.

Comment: See also the edit with 3rd link.  Glad I could talk you around to a better approach, your users will thank you.  :)

Answer (score 4):

As user1329572 says, you'll want to subclass (or *extend*) the `JTextField`. You can do this as follows:

```
public class MyTextField extends javax.swing.JTextField {
    private String /* or whatever type */ myCustomParam;

    public String getCustomParam() {
        return myCustomParam;
    }

    public void setCustomParam(String param) {
        myCustomParam = param;
    }
}
```

Anywhere you need to use a `JTextField`, you can also use a `MyTextField`. All other functions will still work.

Regarding focus: to detect focus, use a `FocusAdapter`:

```
MyTextField mtf = new MyTextField();
mtf.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent e) {
        System.out.println("I lost focus.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the help user1329572 and WChargin.

That custom param, can i set this through the properties menu in netbeans, because if i look at the code that is generated there does not seem to be any way of setting that value?

Comment: Wherever you want to set the value, type the code `setCustomParam(value)`, where value is the value you want to set.